# How to use EF DbFirst with MySQL in .NET Core?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, db-first

I try to use EF with MySQL in my project. And I add:

> MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
>   MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

into my `project.json` but the tools section of `project.json` is empty. When I run:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "myconnectionstr" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -StartupProject "myproject"
```

The console shows me an error:

> Unable to find expected assembly attribute named
>   DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute in provider assembly
>   MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Did this work? Im stuck at the same thing.

Comment: @Yashvit unlucky,i worded with code first at last.

Comment: some times clearing the data from "temp" directory would solve some of the issues,  C:\Users\<logonuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\

Answer (score 5):

It seems that "official" provider `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.7-m61` still unsupports scaffolding. However, it works fine with  `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` free community [provider](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql):

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=foodb;Username=root;Password=mysql" ^
    Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql ^
    --force ^
    --context "FooContext" ^
    --output-dir "Entities" ^
    --verbose
```

Our csproj (Visual Studio 2017):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>    
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.2-preview-10036" />
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.2-preview-10036" />

        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```